# macOS use "Command key" as zsh shorcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

I want to use macOS **command key** as iterm2's **shortcut**. (not an alias, I mean ^W ^E Command-B, etc)
Is this possible?
I search for this question and found some tips in zsh [doc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps).
However, I still cannot fix my problem.

Besides, is there any best practice for writing zle config?
I totally messed up by lots of ways to change my custom terminal shortcuts.

Is there somebody can help?
a detail tutorial article will be great, too

Answer (score 1):

If you're on macOS, rather than trying to configure keyboard shortcuts in every shell and/or terminal you use, it's much easier to just configure it once, on the OS level, with [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org). It even comes with a handy module for it, called [Keyboard shortcuts for terminal apps](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=terminal#terminal_navi), so you don't have to configure it yourself.